# When you see one/her, she is usually busy looking after patients - talking about a general idea

Tags: meaning-in-context, pronouns

In example 1, "one" is used first and then "she" is used; in example 2, "her" is used first and then "she" is used.

To my ears, both examples convey just the concept of a nurse but not a specific nurse, but I am not 100% sure.

So do both of the examples convey the idea of a nurse in general?

What are the differences between the two examples?

**Example 1**

> A nurse is a woman who takes care of patients and assists doctors. When you see **one**, **she** is usually busy looking after patients.

**Example 2**

> A nurse is a woman who takes care of patients and assists doctors. When you see **her**, **she** is usually busy looking after patients.

Comment: Nurses don't have to be female! Your example 1 expresses your meaning better; _when you see her_ normally refers to a particular individual.

Comment: Yes, nurses can be anyone. I didn't want to make the examples complicated by involving the sex-neutral "they" so I assumed they are female in order to keep things simple. How about this one: "A nurse is a woman who takes care of patients and assists doctors. One/she is usually busy looking after patients." I feel like in this case, we should use "she." Why?

Comment: _One_ isn't used as the subject of a sentence (except in the sense of 'people in general' or  when referring to oneself).

Comment: @KateBunting So, both Examples 1 and 2 are correct but using "one" sounds better? And if it is for the subject, like my sentence in my previous comment, I should use "she" and avoid using "one"?

Comment: I don't find Example 2 particularly idiomatic, except possibly in a children's book. Yes, avoid using _one_ as subject - use _She is_ or _They are_.

Comment: @KateBunting "They are" means "nurses in general" in the context of my sentence, right? But in another context, it can be a gender-neutral pronoun, am I correct?

Comment: It could be interpreted either way - it makes no difference to the meaning.